# Uploading Pages made on Dreamweaver to the Internet

Tags: html, ftp, web, dreamweaver

I have created several html pages using Adobe's Dreamweaver. I was wondering what are the steps that I need to take in order to upload these pages onto a live website. I already purchased a domain name.

Basically, I am a newbie who has no idea how to upload HTML documents onto the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need someone to host your website. The DNS records for your domain name should then be pointed to your hosts web servers on the internet. The host will provide you with FTP information to FTP your files up to the web server which your pages will be served from.

Comment: The FTP (File Transfer Protocol) information will include a login name and a password. There are options within dreamweaver to automatically connect to your host using your login and password. It is better to use Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) as it is encrypted and not sending your data (including username and password) unencrypted. When you get it running, share a link to your website!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is get a server to host your files online. Of course, you can use your own computer to host the files but there are some pros and cons to that. Theres the fact that you can get a lot of space but you need your pc to be on all the time.
 Or you can use an online hosting service to host your files. Hosting can be free or paid, and mostly free hosting requires you to use ads on your website. But I'd suggest use x10hosting or 000webhost. Upload all your HTML files (you can log in and upload the files through your internet browser, preferably GOOGLE CHROME, then see your web page come to life on the internet.
 There are a load of things I can talk about but I wont go on about SEO and FTP's, just for now use x10hosting if you are looking for something free and of good quality, or use 000webhosting if youre looking for something free and easy.